# SAPUI5 invalid MIME part type with Remote oDATA Service

Tags: odata, sapui5

I need help showing the data from my own remote server with oDATA.
When I want to show the data in the view, I get the following error
invalid MIME part type.

These are the Captures of Error
[my https://******/$metadata?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jf4Dh.png)

[My Table control from SApui5 Course App example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBEQk.png)

[Error when executing the application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1Rek.png)

[And Console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tM4kw.png)

When I insert this.getModel().setUseBatch(false) in the init : function ()  of the Component.js, it does not give me the error, nor in the console, but it does not show me the records either .. Can someone give me an idea?

Comment: You said issue while binding in the view, you are able to make a read call from the controller?

Comment: your console log shows some http-errors 404 (not found), have you checked them?

Comment: @AnnieW.  exact, but I can not find where that error comes from. This project I use is the SAPUI5 Course w2u1 available at https://github.com/SAP/openSAP-ui5-course, I have not replaced anything, just change the destination of my Remote oData

Comment: @NandanChaturvedi This project is the SAPUI5 w2u1 Course available at https://github.com/SAP/openSAP-ui5-course, I have not replaced anything, just change the destination of my Remote oData. Help me please

Comment: Invalid MIME part type would suggest that the problem is with your XML file. Could you check whether the properties and their types have been configured correctly?

Answer (score 1):

It's an old question, but recently I've got the same error with batch request processing and in my case the root cause was that when building batch processing response with content type multipart/mixed you have to use CRLF as a text line separator ('\r\n') and not only '\n'. See also here in [multipart response specification](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html). The hard part was that correct and incorrect responses look absolutely identical when debugging.